# Wordpress permalinkslug changed page to page__trashed

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

A Wordpress site of mine seems to have changed some of my pages permalinks by adding __trashed after the slug. 
Note that not all pages are affected, neither do other post types.

Anyone might have seen the same problem & a clue what might have caused it? I can remove it manualy, but it's kind of weird and I don't want it to happen again :)

I'm using WP v 4.5.3 & the plugins are up to date.

plugins used:

- Bulletproof security
- comet cache (former zencache, former quick cache)
- Yoast SEO
- Mailpoet
- Captcha by BestWebSoft
- Event organiser
- ACF

Answer (score 0):

Posted my question above also @ the Wordpress forums, it seems to be caused by the Press permit addon pack: PP Collaborative Editing Pack

It changes page names when you edit and save your sites menu.

For more info, see this thread: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-permalinkslug-changed-page-to-page_trashed/

Answer (score 0):

Simply export the page then change the page title (existing) then import the exported page. When a page shows trashed in permalink then not considered as a page so you need to remove that.
no need of deletion the existing page with trashed in permalink before a fresh copy imported.
I changed http://www.artbabyalbania.com/trashed/homepage-4 to http://www.artbabyalbania.com/homepage-4 to **http://www.artbabyalbania.com**/ (set as a front static page from settings)

Answer (score 0):

quick edit the page and change the slug. I changed https://restorify.io/jobs and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Install the WP-Optimize - Clean, Compress, Cache plugin and run the recommended settings in the first installation and it will fix it.